# How to make convert return string in xlsx2csv？

Tags: python, csv

https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv

This project has only one file, which looks easy to understand, but I don't know how to modify it so that it outputs the result string instead of directly inputting it into the file.

I want it not to output to a file, but to return a string. But I can't understand the code. How should I modify it

```
writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=self.options['quoting'], delimiter=self.options['delimiter'],

lineterminator=self.options['lineterminator'])
```

Comment: I guess in principle you would have to take the instances of `writer.write` - this is where data is written to the csv - and instead write to a string variable (which you will have to make sure is returned appropriately). What is your goal here with an entire excel file in a string? Generally speaking, that will not be a very good data structure to work with data from an excel file!

Comment: Why can't you simply read that file newely created to string & print it?

Comment: @topsail I want xlsx to be converted into txt, and it can be stored in my own way, so I've been trying to figure out how to output strings so that I can store them in my own way.

Comment: @Bhargav Isn't this more complicated? Should be able to read the string directly?

Comment: The simple solution is as Bhargav said - use the library code to write to csv, then read the csv into a string. That is not more complicated because it uses a standard built in python operations - reading a csv file. It is hard to say much more about why this might be good or bad without knowing what your goal is - how you want to store the excel data in your "own way". Since xlsx2csv writes csv data, it probably will be essentially the same whether you read the file or get the output as a long string.

Comment: There are other libraries you can explore...is it compulosry to use only this library?

Comment: Yes, this library can read xlsx files relatively quickly. I tried to use openpyxl to read Excel tables, and it was very slow.

Comment: output = io.StringIO()
Xlsx2csv(r"C:\Users\Gaoyongxian\PycharmProjects\Y_searcher\demo.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert(output,0)
with open("demo.txt","w",encoding="utf8") as f:
    print(output.getvalue())
    f.write(output.getvalue())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = io.StringIO()
Xlsx2csv(r"C:\Users\Gaoyongxian\PycharmProjects\Y_searcher\demo.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert(output,0)
with open("demo.txt","w",encoding="utf8") as f:
    print(output.getvalue())
    f.write(output.getvalue())
```